# calculating sentiment index with hourly time range

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

**df**

```
date                     Score        sent_index
2017-03-02 01:01:04.000    0.038889      na
2017-03-02 01:12:10.726    0.112000      na
2017-03-02 01:33:58.001    -0.134991     na
2017-03-02 01:39:51.000     0            na
2017-03-02 01:39:52.000     -0.9338      0.87(example score from 01:01:04.000 to 01:39:52.000)    
 .
 .                           next hour scores
 .                           and so on up to 018
 2018-05-24 01:00:00.000
```

This table is head of pandas data frame that contains values from 2017 to 2018. I have already calculated sentiment score in next column using 'Score' column: number of positive counts, negative count and neural counts with the following code:

```
sent_range=df[d_start:d_end]
pos = (sent_range.scores>0).sum()
neg =(sent_range.scores<0).sum()
other=(sent_range.scores==0).sum()
index=(pos-neg)/other
```

postiveCounts - negative count/ all counts (All counts happens during one hours time period)

expected Dataframe should look like:

```
date                      Score        sent_index
DELETED                    0.038889      na
DELETED                    0.112000      na
DELETED                    -0.134991     na
DELETED                     0            na
2017-03-02 02:00:00        -0.9338       0.87(example score from 01:01:04.000 to 01:39:52.000)    
 .
 .                           next hour scores
 .                           and so on up to 018
 2018-05-24 01:00:00.000
```

- now, `sent_index` is right now empty and I want to fill out this column and want to  merge all times for column 'date' into **one** on hourly basis, because **one** sentiment score will be calculated  for all observation in **score column** (0.87) during one hour time period. like `2017-03-02 01:00:00` to `2017-03-02 1:59:00` into single time `2017-03-02 2:00:00` (score for first hour is  `0.87`). This sequence in data continues up to 2018 (approx: 6000) for both of columns: timestamps, polarity, and score*
  I shall be grateful for any help. Thank in advance.

Comment: If you are dealing with timeseries data, you should read the doc about [how to handle it in pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#). Basically, you need to create a `DatetimeIndex` and  do rolling operation on it with a `timedelta` offset. I would like to write an example for you, but i just can't figure out how you got `0.87` from the sample data. Your code `index=(pos-neg)/other ` says it is `(2-2)/1= 0`.

Comment: Thanks. 0.87 is actually an imaginary score not real